# Not able to provide background color for a row in excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook

I have an excel file with extension xls. I want to give a background color of all the rows based on the first column value of each row .
My code is not working based on my requirement .Back ground color is happening but not as per the requirement .
I am using apache POI jar for implementation .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class DemoPainter {

public void colorSheet() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(
            "/vobs/SampleFile.xls");
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fi);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    System.out.println("Sheet Name: " + sheet.getSheetName());
    startColor(sheet, wb);
}

public void startColor(HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFWorkbook wb) throws IOException {

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++){
        Row row=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        Cell cell=row.getCell(0);
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        if(cell.getStringCellValue().equals("modified")){
            setYellowColor(wb,row);
        }
        else if(cell.getStringCellValue().equals("removed")){
            setRedColor();
        }
        else {
            setGreenColor();
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/vobs/SampleFile1.xls"));
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}

public void setYellowColor(HSSFWorkbook wb,Row row){
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    System.out.println("started Yellow color");
    style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    row.setRowStyle(style);
}

public void setRedColor(){

}

public void setGreenColor(){

}
```

}

[Required Output excel sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnf20.png) ,
[Current Output excel sheet image based on my code behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmOb8.png)

Can anyone help here ?

Comment: Two problems immediately obvious: #1 - Cell Styles are workbook scoped, so don't create one for every row! Create them once up front. #2 - You're not styling the individual completed cells in the rows. Row styles are a default, then don't apply to cells with their own styles, so style the cells too!

Comment: Got my solution.. I created style object per row. and colored all the cells  of the corresponding row .

Answer (score 1):

Promoting a comment to an answer....

You have two problems. Problem #1 - Cell Styles are workbook scoped, so don't create one for every row! Create them once up front, otherwise you'll exceed the maximum number of styles allowed by Excel in a Workbook.

Problem #2 - You're not styling the individual completed cells in the rows. Row styles are a default, which apply to new cells added in Excel. They don't apply to already existing cells, as when a cell is created it always has a reference to an applied style. So, you need to set your cell style on the existing cells in the row too

Bonus problem #3 - You've harded coded in `HSSF` everywhere, so your code will only work with `XLS` files. See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html for how to change your code to be general and work for `XLSX` too

Change your code to be more like....

```
File input = new File("/vobs/SampleFile.xls");
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
System.out.println("Sheet Name: " + sheet.getSheetName());

CellStyle yellow = wb.createCellStyle();
yellow.setFillForegroundColor(Color.YELLOW.index);
yellow.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

// And Red etc

for (Row r : sheet) {
   Cell c1 = r.getCell(0);
   if (c1 == null) {
      // Empty row
      continue;
   }
   // Get cell as string
   String val = formatter.formatCellValue(c1);

   // Check
   if(val.equals("modified")) {
      r.setRowStyle(yellow);
      for (Cell c : r) {
         c.setCellStyle(yellow);
      }
    }
    else if(val.equals("removed")){
       // etc
    }
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/vobs/Changed.xls"));
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```